# Pandas merge on exact match and date column with condition

Tags: python, pandas, merge, duplicates

I want to use pd.merge to left join df1 to df2, using ID and Company as exact matches and match dates where df1['Date1'] is greater than df2['Date2']. The issue is I get duplicates because df2 has multiple matches.

df1:

```
Company   Revenue     ID        Date1
 XX       1000.0    12345x    2020-02-11
 XX       6000.0    12345x    2020-01-02
 AA       5000.0    12346a    2019-12-20
 BB       100.0     22345x    2019-11-07
 FF       18000.0   32345x    2020-01-11
```

df2:

```
Company   Clicks     ID         Date2
 XX       1         12345x    2019-07-11
 XX       0         12345x    2020-01-10
 AA       0         12346a    2019-12-27
 BB       1         22345x    2019-11-07
 FF       1         32345x    2019-03-11
 FF       0         32345x    2019-08-28
```

I have tried using all types of merges, dropping duplicates from df2 and even using groupby.

```
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, by=['Company','ID'], left_on='Date1', right_on='Date2', allow_exact_matches=False)
```

I have played around with other parameters for merge_asof i.e. direction='forward' and tolerance but it isn't working.
I basically to pull in matches from df2 where the Date2 is before Date1 with no repeating dates/matches. In the case where Company = 'FF', I would prefer to match the record where Clicks is greater than 0 if possible.

Expected output:

```
Company   Revenue     ID        Date1      Date2        Clicks
 XX       1000.0    12345x    2020-02-11   2020-01-10    0
 XX       6000.0    12345x    2020-01-02   2019-07-11    1
 AA       5000.0    12346a    2019-12-20   N/A           N/A
 BB       100.0     22345x    2019-11-07   N/A           N/A
 FF       18000.0   32345x    2020-01-11   2019-03-11    1
```

Comment: How 2019-03-11    with click =1 ?

Comment: `pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('Date1'), df2.sort_values('Date2'), by=['Company','ID'], left_on='Date1', right_on='Date2', allow_exact_matches=False)
`

Comment: my mistake, sorry about that. merge_asof gives me duplicates.